# Logging missing jar files during load of Java applet

Tags: java, image, logging, exception, jar

I have an applet which uses a lot of Jar files when loading the code.

As I am caching these Jar files, I have append a version number in their file name, so I have a file called images_4.jar.

Sometimes I screw up and input a wrong Jar file in my HTML, and when I try to load my applet, it will complain about a missing Jar file.

Is there anyway that I can catch these exception or error in the Java code ? I have a logging tool which I use in the Java applet to report errors to my server, but is there a way to use this approach to report missing Jar files ?

I could listen for a Missing Class File Exception, but sometimes my Jar files only contain images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround the image loading with a `try`/`catch`..

BTW - how exactly does the code load images?  `ImageIO.read(..)` throws informative exceptions, whereas a lot of image loading methods just fail silently.

Comment: I could surround the image loading with a try/catch, but I have a lot of other files also being loaded like Audio and txt files.


You could argue that I could pipe all my loading throught a single loading method surrounded by a try/catch, but this approach seems very tedious for me due to my larger number of code lines I would have to change to allow for this change for work.


To answer your question I use getResourceAsStream on the contextClassLoader to load my images.

Comment: *"You could argue that I could pipe all my loading throught a single loading method surrounded by a try/catch, but this approach seems very tedious for me due to my larger number of code lines I would have to change to allow for this change for work."*  Better now than later. *"I use getResourceAsStream"*  That's good.  It won't fail silently.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that. A quick look around my code I found out that I already am piping all resource loading through this method, making it a prime example of where to put my try/catch.